# C++ difference between method signatures while passing objects to it

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I see that there are three distinct ways of passing an object to a function in C++. Assuming my class to be like this:

```
class Test {
    int i;
public:
    Test(int x);
    int getX();
    void setX(int num);
};

Test::Test(int x) {
    i = x;
}

int Test::getX() {
    return i;
}

void Test::setX(int num) {
  i = num;
}
```

these three signatures can pass an object of class `Test` to the method:

```
void temp(Test obj) {
    obj.setX(100);
}

void perm(Test *obj) {
    obj->setX(150);
}

void noidea(Test &obj) {
    obj.setX(150);
}
```

As it turns out, the second and third methods impact the caller, the same object i being modified inside the function, whereas in the first one, it juts makes a bitwise copy of the object, and thus doesn't impact the caller (if the copy modifies pointer members or resources, it can impact the caller).

Barring this, is there any other difference in the signatures?

And can someone explain the 3rd signature? I can understand the second, you call it like `int retVal = perm(&object)`, where `object` is of class `Test`. The address is captured by `obj` in the function parameter, since it is the address of an object of class `Test`, the type is a pointer to object of class `Test`, thus using indirection to access its members. But how does the third signature work, and what exactly is passed to it when `noidea(object)` is called, and what exactly is the type of `obj` int the function parameter?

Comment: In the first one, it doesn't make a bitwise copy, but it makes a copy using the default copy constructor.  The difference is subbtle but important.

Comment: Umm, I have read in a couple of books and sites that it does so. Some use the term **member-wise copy**. Though they are the same, except of course, the exceptions, which I mentioned.

Comment: member-whise copy means that every member is copied.  For a simple data structure made out of fundamental types, it's indeed bitwaise copy.  But as soon as one of the member of your object has a type with it's own copy constructor / assignment operator (for example a std::string), this one is called for the copy, making sure that the member is copied by using appropriate semantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First difference between first and other two is that latter two cases avoid unnecessary copying of objects apart from difference you pointed out. This could make difference when your class size if large.

Difference between second and third is the difference between passing by pointer and passing by reference. Passing by pointer means you are taking the address of memory location of passed argument whereas reference is just an alias for passed argument.

EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT:-

```
void func( int& a )
{
}

int x;
func(x);
```

In this "a" would just be another alias for memory allocated to variable "x" ( OR you can say that a would be a nick name for variable x so that any changes to "a" would be applied to "x" also ). So ,any modification to "a" done in func would indirectly be applied to variable "x".

DIFFERENCE BETWEEN PASSING BY REFERENCE AND BY POINTER:-

Both are basically same as far as behavior and efficiency is concerned. However, there are subtle differences.

1) Passing pointer to function means you have to put a check for NULL before using it. Whereas there is no such thing as NULL reference in C++ so you can get rid of that.

NOTE:- Although you can make a NULL reference indirectly like:-

```
int * ptr = NULL;
int &a = *ptr;
```

But this hardly of any sense.

2) Second if you are passing reference than in that function you cannot reassign reference to some other object ( Since reference are bound at initialization to particular object till its lifetime )but you can do it with pointer. For e.g:-

Pointers:-

```
int x = 4;
int *ptr = &x;
func(ptr);

void func( int *ptr )
{
 int y = 2;
 ptr = &y;    //pointer changed to point to y.It's perfectly fine.
}
```

References:-

```
int x = 4;
func(x);

void func( int& a )
{
 int y= 2;
 a = y;        //compiler would shout.This is not allowed.
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the passing by reference in bit more detail?

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between passing it as reference and pointer? Both work with the memory location, and thus change the passed object permanently, correct?

Comment: @Cupidvogel Please see my updated answer and let me know if you still have any doubts...

Comment: Can you give an example for the second difference?

Comment: @Cupidvogel huh...Please check

Answer (score 2):

The third calling convention technically works like the second:  the compiler will generate code behind the scene that will take the adress of the object. And technically speaking, the reference is like a const pointer, but you don't have to dereference it.

The semantics are not totally similar though:

- in the third approach you really have to provide an object as parameter, while in the second you could still do some pointer arithmetics and function calls to determine the adress
- in the third you cannot pass a `nullptr`
- in fact with the reference, everything works as if you would use the original object with another name.

For more about semantic difference look for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29).

**Experimental demonstration:**

In case of further interest, here the generated assembler code for the call:

```
; 45   :    temp(t);            ; Call by value:  
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _t$[ebp]    ; Moves the content of the object  
    push    eax                    ; Put it on stack 
    call    ?temp@@YAXVTest@@@Z    ; Call temp
    add esp, 4            
; 46   :    perm(&t);            ; Call by address: 
    lea eax, DWORD PTR _t$[ebp]    ; Moves the adress of the object 
    push    eax                    ; Put it on the stack 
    call    ?perm@@YAXPAVTest@@@Z  ; Call perm 
    add esp, 4
; 47   :    noidea(t);           ; Call by reference: 
    lea eax, DWORD PTR _t$[ebp]    ; Exactly the same code as with pointes
    push    eax
    call    ?noidea@@YAXAAVTest@@@Z ; but with noidea
    add esp, 4
```

The assembler code generated for `perm()` is EXACTLY the same then for `noidea()` (except the values 100 and 150).  I don't show it here, but if you're interested let me know.

And for the experiments about difference in semantics:  try to do do `obj++;` at the end of `perm()` and `noidea()`:  the first will compile (increment obj pointer) while the second not (you cannot increment the object itself because the `++` operator is not defined for the class `Test`).